# ¿Se puede acotar la zona de actuación de un controlador en AngularJs?

Tags: angularjs

El problema que me encuentro es que el `Frontend` dispone de una barra de información de la aplicación (php) me retorna información sobre la ejecución del `Backend`.

Dentro de esta información, hay ciertos valores de configuración de este estilo:

```
'config/autoload/{{,*.}global,{,*.}local}.php'
```

Además de otros similares que pertenecen a los enrutadores y demás.

El tema es que `AngularJs` intenta interpretar esta información y lanza errores en la consola. Y se hace un poco difícil seguir otros errores durante el desarrollo.

El `html` tiene una estructura básica:

```
<html ng-app="App">
    <head></head>
    <body ng-controller="AngularController">
        <header></header>
        <main></main>
        <footer></footer>
        <!-- Aquí se cargan los datos del backend -->
    </body>
</html>
```

Con estos antecedentes vuelvo de nuevo al título de la pregunta.

**¿Se puede acotar la zona de actuación de un controlador en AngularJs para evitar la parte del html que causa los errores?**

Por ejemplo que solo actúe sobre la etiqueta `<main>`.

O al contrario, que evite actuar sobre una parte específica del `html`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Si, poniendo el ng-controller en la etiqueta donde quieres que actue, si la pones en main, su scope será el div main:

```
<html ng-app="App">
    <head></head>
    <body>
        <header></header>
        <main ng-controller="AngularController"></main>
        <footer></footer>
        <!-- Aquí se cargan los datos del backend -->
    </body>
</html>
```

Edito mi Respuesta, Creo que podrías utilizar  ng-non-bindable en el/los tags que deseas que Angular no interprete.

[Fuente](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngNonBindable)

Comment: Se puede hacer así, pero me obliga a quitar el `ng-app` de la etiqueta `html` y asignarla al menos a la misma etiqueta del controlador. Si no muevo el `ng-app` continua dando errores.

Comment: Ahi edite mi respuesta

Comment: Eso funcionó perfectamente!!